# Youtube ios feed thumbnail

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I'm creating an app to pull in my friends youtube feed. When I run the app I receive an error:

```
2013-03-30 16:34:04.973 eastcoastdyes[15395:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initWithString:relativeToURL:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a38012 0x1354e7e 0x1a37deb 0xd4a49d 0xdc11e4 0x3859 0x3538fb 0x3539cf 0x33c1bb 0x34cb4b 0x2e92dd 0x13686b0 0x3014fc0 0x300933c 0x3009150 0x2f870bc 0x2f88227 0x2f888e2 0x1a00afe 0x1a00a3d 0x19de7c2 0x19ddf44 0x19dde1b 0x19927e3 0x1992668 0x298ffc 0x231d 0x2245 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellID = @"Cell Identifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    NSDictionary *video = [self.videos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [video objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [video objectForKey:@"uploader"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[video objectForKey:@"data.items.thumbnail.hqdefault"]];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    return cell;
```

}

I receive it at the NSURL *url.. help please

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an error because your dictionary is returning a nil object for that key... Thus you should first ensure your `video` dictionary returns a non-nil object (string), for your `@"data.items.thumbnail.hqdefault"` key, and only then initialize your URL...

e.g.

```
NSString *imageURLString = [video valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.thumbnail.hqdefault"]; 
if (imageURLString) {
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:imageURLString];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];
} else {
// set imageView to something else
}
```

Comment: why is it returning a nil object?

Comment: Your key is either incorrect or there was never a string set for that key.

Comment: You cannot, I repeat cannot use `key paths` with -objectForKey:. It simply will not work. If you must use a key path instead of multiple `-objectForKey:` calls, use `-valueForKeyPath:` instead.

Comment: I used this https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc#Requesting_JSONC_Feeds and thumbnail is the correct object for path

Comment: I updated to reflect `valueForKeyPath:`... woops. So perhaps that string is never set and your video object is incomplete. Safeguards are still a good idea though.. I use them everywhere... Also here's the `NSDictionary` class reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html